# How to solve IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: handleActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-activity, in-app-purchase

I implemented in app billing using Trivial Drive sample code.
I kill app using task killer while in sub activity which is called by startActivityForResult.
I restart app and push back button to come back to the root activity, it crashes at handleActivityResult. When app restarts, it starts from sub activity. IAB helper setup is done in the root activity, not sub activity. So, it causes this error.

How can I solve this problem?
I use task killer to simulate Android kills app when memory is low.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Can we see the logcat?

Comment: void checkSetupDone(String operation) {
        if (!mSetupDone) {
            logError("Illegal state for operation (" + operation + "): IAB helper is not set up.");
            throw new IllegalStateException("IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: " + operation);
        }
    }
Sorry, I can't. checkSetupDone is called in handleActivityResult. Because mSetupDone is null, it causes exception.

Comment: I found just before that onCreate of root activity is also called when app is restarted. I don't understand why mSetupDone is null even though it is setup again in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and it works.
Only when it is returned from in app billing call, I call handleActivityResult.
returnFromActivity is global variable and set true in sub activities of my app.
I don't know why mSetupDone is null and how other people solved this problem.
Please let me know if there is better solution.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (!returnFromActivity) {
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    ....................
}
```